# CSS Form align buttons and checkboxes

Tags: css, forms

I'm editing a form and need to reduce the space between the buttons and checkboxes. I need also to put the checkboxes on the second line, aligned with the buttons on the first one, in order to avoid the third line. Any help?

**WHAT I HAVE NOW**

[image]

**MY CSS**

```
        input[type="checkbox"] + label:before,
        input[type="radio"] + label:before {
        border: solid 1px;
        content: '';
        display: inline-block;
        height: 1.65em;
        left: 0;
        line-height: 1.58125em;
        position: absolute;
        text-align: center;
        top: 0;
        width: 1.65em;
    }
```

Comment: Use Display flex and flex-wrap.

Comment: @vishugosain my CSS knowledge is limited, can you detail a little bit?

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle ? I can edit it for you.

Answer (score 0):

For an exact answer, I need a HTML. But maybe just

```
left: -.5em;
```

or

```
label {
  margin-left: -.5em;
}
```